# Moodle 2.x task automation for create / copy course

Tags: moodle

is there a good clean way in moodle to programmatically create new courses and copy old courses? At the moment I try to figure out whats possible with moodles webservices, since the cli scripts are lousy. But it seems that with webservices only the creation of courses is possible. Copying one is not a possible task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a site administrator, automated course backups are more expensive in terms of time, CPU usage and storage. The recovery time to have a site running again takes longer than a site backup. However, teachers and site administrators might find a course backups as a way to create a "fresh" copy of a course that can be re-used.

Use Default Moodle Functionality Backup & Restore, it's easy for you, and for create course you can also use web service.

Comment: Hey and thanks for you answer. We want to give our users the ability to port old courses to the new Semester. At the moment we manually create a backup and restore the selected course in a new section for the semester. Do you know a way to do that task per for example webservice?